# Why does Scalatra give me a FlashMap casting error sometimes?

Tags: scala, scalatra, scalate

When running Scalatra in code reload mode, if I load the page before the scalate engine has reinitialized I get a 500 error.

If I watch the terminal until it looks like the engine has fully reloaded, it works fine, but I think this happens when I load the page between a) successful compile, and b) the container restart.

This won't correct itself until I change something else and force a new compile and code reload.

I can't seem to find why this is happening, does anyone have any ideas?

Here is how I'm doing code reloading:

```
./sbt "container:start" "~ ;copy-resources;aux-compile"
```

Here is the error I see:

```
HTTP ERROR 500

Problem accessing /. Reason:

    org.scalatra.FlashMap cannot be cast to org.scalatra.FlashMap
Caused by:

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.scalatra.FlashMap cannot be cast to org.scalatra.FlashMap
    at org.scalatra.FlashMapSupport$$anonfun$org$scalatra$FlashMapSupport$$getFlash$2$$anonfun$1.apply(flashMap.scala:182)
    at org.scalatra.FlashMapSupport$$anonfun$org$scalatra$FlashMapSupport$$getFlash$2$$anonfun$1.apply(flashMap.scala:182)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at org.scalatra.FlashMapSupport$$anonfun$org$scalatra$FlashMapSupport$$getFlash$2.apply(flashMap.scala:181)
    at org.scalatra.FlashMapSupport$$anonfun$org$scalatra$FlashMapSupport$$getFlash$2.apply(flashMap.scala:180)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.scalatra.FlashMapSupport$class.org$scalatra$FlashMapSupport$$getFlash(flashMap.scala:180)
    at org.scalatra.FlashMapSupport$class.flash(flashMap.scala:192)
    at beekeeper.controllers.HomeServlet.flash(HomeServlet.scala:13)
    at org.scalatra.FlashMapSupport$$anonfun$handle$1.apply$mcV$sp(flashMap.scala:137)
    at org.scalatra.FlashMapSupport$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(flashMap.scala:136)
    at org.scalatra.FlashMapSupport$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(flashMap.scala:136)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at org.scalatra.DynamicScope$class.withRequest(DynamicScope.scala:71)
    at org.scalatra.ScalatraServlet.withRequest(ScalatraServlet.scala:49)
    at org.scalatra.FlashMapSupport$class.handle(flashMap.scala:136)
    at beekeeper.controllers.HomeServlet.handle(HomeServlet.scala:13)
    at org.scalatra.ScalatraServlet.service(ScalatraServlet.scala:54)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1072)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1006)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: It seems fairly obvious that you can't make requests to the server until it is done purging all the old classes. If you don't wait long enough, incompatibilities arise as you can see. The real bug is that your server allows you to make connections while it is reloading...

Answer (score 0):

This error says that there are 2 instances of the same class, loaded by different class loaders. This behavior rooted in java: classes from different class loaders are not the same. Basically equals method for classes is the function of a class name and a class loader. Classes will not be the same in this case even if they come from the same jar or folder.

When container reloads code it creates a new class loader, while your session still holds instance of flash map loaded using old class loader. This most likely the cause of the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So I get that there are multiple class loaders, but shouldn't the container reload drop the old class loader? Why does it stick around until a second restart?

Comment: idk, perhaps there is a bug in jetty class loading also check if you have 2 libraries with the same FlashMap in your classpath (which I doubt). Old version of class should not be kept until second restart of course. Unless you use some fancy classloading yourself, I doubt you can do anything except upgrading jetty.

Answer (score 0):

In Java every class is identified by its **fully qualified class name** and the **class loader that has loaded it**, this implies that:

```
ClassLoader1.my.package.MyClass != ClassLoader2.my.package.MyClass
```

This signifiy that it is not possible to cast an object of class `MyClass` loaded in `ClassLoader1` to type `MyClass` loaded from `ClassLoader2`. You can find more details on

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html

On the other hand, it is not possible to load the same class **twice** in the same class loader, so you need a new class loader, there is no way around it. While I never wrote code that performs class reloading, one can suppose that class reloading means in practice:

- create a new class loader
- reload the class
- swap class loaders

Because of what described above, one needs to be careful when designing classes that are supposed to be reloaded: see http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html#designing